# Finding value of 2 bytes in Java

Tags: java, byte

I am trying to find the value of the first 2 bytes in a UDP packet which corresponds to the length of the remaining payload. What is the best method to find this value in Java given that I know the first 2 bytes? Would `java.nio.ByteBuffer` be of any use?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get a 16-bit integer from two 8-bit integers?

Comment: Documentation only states that payload length is in first 2 bytes. Probably just a single 16-bit integer instead of adding two 8-bit integers.

Comment: Epic discussion for such a simple problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use something like this:

```
static public int buildShort(byte high, byte low)
{
  return ((0xFF & (int) high) * 256) + ((0xFF & (int) low));
}
```

Then you take first two bytes of your `DatagramPacket`:

```
int length = buildShort(packet.getData()[0], packet.getData()[1]);
```

Mind that I used length as an `int` because also `short` data type (as everyone) is signed in Java, so you need a larger space.

Comment: I prefer Justin's and erickson's style, e.g. "<< 8" instead of "* 256" and "|" instead of "+", since what you are doing is really shifting and combining bits (which can also be interpreted as multiplication and addition, but obscuring a bit the intention).

By the way, not _all_ integral primitive types are signed: char!

Comment: Yeah, operators don't involve any difference in performance (since JIT will do the dirty work of optimizing this with bitwise operators by itself).. it's just a matter of taste :)

Comment: @Dimitris: Well, I disagree: what you are *really* doing is the multiplication and addition to convert a base-256 encoded integer into a java integer. It is just lucky coincidence that the encoding base is a power of two. Well, off course not really lucky, it is done that way for the efficiency. So I guess we're both correct.

Answer (score 3):

Using a `ByteBuffer` is convenient, just don't get tripped up by Java signed 16-bit values:

```
byte[] data = new byte[MAX_LEN];
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
DatagramPacket pkt = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
⋮    
while (connected) {
  socket.receive(pkt);
  int len = buf.getShort() & 0xFFFF;
  ⋮
}
```

If you don't want to use `ByteBuffer`, the conversion is still fairly easy. The equivalent multiplication and addition can be used, but I see bit operators used more frequently:

```
int len = (data[0] & 0xFF) << 8 | data[1] & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed make use of `java.nio.ByteBuffer`. Here's a kickoff example:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
buffer.put(byte1);
buffer.put(byte2);
int length = buffer.getShort(0) & 0xFFFF; // Get rid of sign.
```

Comment: This does get you the ability to switch between network and windows byte order, but at the expense of an object allocation (and some extra logic)

Comment: Also, if you are using 2 byte length, you should up convert to int() to get rid of the sign (`((int)buffer.getShort(0)) | 0xFFFF`)

Comment: @Justin: you're right. You would like to end up with unsigned value.

Answer (score 1):

Using ByteBuffer would only be of value if you are reading the UDP packets (using nio).  You can create a utility method:

```
static final int getLength(DatagramPacket packet) {
 byte data[] = DatagramPacket.getData();
 return (int)((0xFF & (int)data[0]) << 8) | (0xFF & (int)data[1]));
}
```

Comment: ByteBuffer's have excellent support for interpreting byte arrays as various kinds of primitive types, including support for big and little endian.

Comment: True, there is a trade-off here: you are trading the allocation costs (and subsequent garbage collection) of the ByteBuffer against the cost of 2 range checked memory access for data[0], data[1].  Unless you use the ByteBuffer as the source for the DatagramChannel to read into, I don't think it pays off.

Comment: All `(int)` casts are redundant. Otherwise, it's a way to go.

Comment: People are amazingly stubborn about their answers. Your answer is great except the first sentence, which is terrible. It's true that using a ByteBuffer will probably a tiny bit slower, but both are essentially the same. IMHO, Java is not about micro-optimization, and the "pay off" is not in CPU cycles it is in programmer cycles. You might argue that your solution is more clear then bringing in something as obscure as a ByteBuffer, a fair argument. My experience is that ByteBuffers add uniformity and clarity to the problem of converting byte arrays into various kinds of java ints.

Comment: +1 for recognizing stubbornness, though 'programmer cycles' can have various meaning: with ByteBuffer we have introduced a dependency on nio, which means we are not 1.4 portable, we want an unsigned result, but ByteBuffer doesn't offer it, and we introduced a class used for one purpose (an I/O buffer) which is really being used as a utility method for reading one int.